Select Specific Values from a row in a Power BI table based on a Date Condition using DAX
Sample Table - Updated
I need to be able to identify which KPI Name has a value of M or H in the last consecutive 3 months within the available date values for that KPI. I have highlighted in red the KPI names that should be returned in this example. Notice that it doesn't have to be the last 3 months from the current date but just where a date value is available as long as it includes a combination of MMH, MHH, MMM, HHH, HMM, HHM in 3 consecutive months. However, if a value other than M or H or a blank exists after any 3 consecutive months with values of M or H, then it shouldn't be counted. See KRI Name "Average Resolution Time".
The solution could be just a simple Yes or No value that I could then use to filter the table.

[enter image description here][1]

Remember, if a value other than M or H or a blank exists after any 3 consecutives month with values of M or H, then it shouldn't be counted. See KRI Name "Average resolution Time".

Business Rules


The table should only return values that meet the following business rules:

a.  It should only identify when a KPI has either an M or H in 3 consecutive months, prior or equal to the last available date for that KPI.
b.  There could be nothing but blanks between the 3 consecutive months that includes the set of 3 values mentioned, but there can’t be any other value, single or consecutive,  other than M or H or blanks followed by another non consecutive set of 3 values that includes a combination of MMH, MHH, MMM, HHH, HMM, HHM.
Here are the names of the tables and fields  I am using

Column Names

•   'Monthly KPI Log'
•   'Monthly KPI Log'[KPI Name]
•   'Monthly KPI Log'[Value]
•   'Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date]



<table>
    <tr>
        <td>KPI ID</td>
        <td>KPI Name</td>
        <td>Jan-24</td>
        <td>Feb-24</td>
        <td>Mar-24</td>
        <td>Apr-24</td>
        <td>May-24</td>
        <td>Jun-24</td>
        <td>Jul-24</td>
        <td>Aug-24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Average Resolution Time</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Customer Retention Rate</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Employee Turnover Rate</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>First Call Resolution (FCR)</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Inventory Turnover</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Net Promoter Score (NPS)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>On-Time Delivery Rate</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Operational Efficiency Ratio</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>




I can't see the screenshot. Could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Thank you for your message. I just uploaded a sample image and an HTOM table with the sample data. Thanks!

is this the raw data or the matrix table?

Assuming your data table is similar to the below:



KPI ID
KPI Name
Value
Metric Collection Date




9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/01/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/02/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/03/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
L
01/04/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
L
01/05/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/06/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/07/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
M
01/08/2024


9
Average Resolution Time

01/09/2024


9
Average Resolution Time

01/10/2024


9
Average Resolution Time
H
01/11/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
H
01/01/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
H
01/02/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
M
01/03/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
L
01/04/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
M
01/05/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
M
01/06/2024


4
Customer Retention Rate
H
01/07/2024


1
Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT
L
01/01/2024


1
Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT
L
01/02/2024


1
Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT
L
01/03/2024


1
Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT

01/04/2024


1
Customer Satisfaction Score (CSAT

01/05/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
M
01/01/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
M
01/02/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
M
01/03/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/04/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/05/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/06/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/07/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
M
01/08/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/09/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/10/2024


3
Employee Turnover Rate
H
01/11/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
H
01/01/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
M
01/02/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
H
01/03/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)

01/04/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)

01/05/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)

01/06/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
H
01/07/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
M
01/08/2024


10
First Call Resolution (FCR)
H
01/09/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/01/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/02/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/03/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/04/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/05/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/06/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/07/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
H
01/08/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
M
01/09/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
M
01/10/2024


8
Inventory Turnover
M
01/11/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)

01/01/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)

01/02/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
M
01/03/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
M
01/04/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
L
01/05/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
L
01/06/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
L
01/07/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
H
01/08/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
H
01/09/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
L
01/10/2024


2
Net Promoter Score (NPS)
L
01/11/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
L
01/01/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
L
01/02/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
L
01/03/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate

01/04/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate

01/05/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate

01/06/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
L
01/07/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
M
01/08/2024


7
On-Time Delivery Rate
M
01/09/2024


6
Operational Efficiency Ratio
H
01/01/2024


6
Operational Efficiency Ratio
H
01/02/2024


6
Operational Efficiency Ratio

01/03/2024


6
Operational Efficiency Ratio

01/04/2024


6
Operational Efficiency Ratio
H
01/05/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
L
01/01/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
L
01/02/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
L
01/03/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
M
01/04/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
H
01/05/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
H
01/06/2024


5
Revenue Growth Rate
H
01/07/2024



You can try a Measure similar to:
Show KPI = 
  // get all dates for this KPI
  var tblDates = CALCULATETABLE('Monthly KPI Log', REMOVEFILTERS('Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date]))

  // get latest date of this KPI
  var kpiLastDate =
    CALCULATE(
      MAX('Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date]),
      tblDates,
      NOT ISBLANK('Monthly KPI Log'[Value])
    )

  // get month 1 valid KPI date
  var kpiFirstDate =
    CALCULATE(
      MAX('Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date]),
      tblDates,
      'Monthly KPI Log'[Value] IN { "H", "M"},
      (EOMONTH(kpiLastDate, -3) + 1) <= 'Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date] && 'Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date] <= EOMONTH(kpiLastDate, -2)
    )

  // last 3 months rows
  var tblRows3Month =
    FILTER(
      tblDates,
      NOT ISBLANK(kpiFirstDate) && kpiFirstDate <= 'Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date] && 'Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date] <= kpiLastDate
    )

  // count valid distinct months
  var validMonthRows = 
    COUNTROWS(
      DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
          FILTER(tblRows3Month, 'Monthly KPI Log'[Value] IN { "H", "M"} ),
          "MonthNum", MONTH('Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date])
        )
      )
    )

  // count invalid distinct months
  var invalidMonthRows = 
    COUNTROWS(
      DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
          FILTER(tblRows3Month, NOT 'Monthly KPI Log'[Value] IN { "H", "M"} && NOT ISBLANK('Monthly KPI Log'[Value]) ),
          "MonthNum", MONTH('Monthly KPI Log'[Metric Collection Date])
        )
      )
    )

  return IF(validMonthRows = 3 && invalidMonthRows < 1, 1)

Then you can add this Measure as a visual filter to your matrix, like so:

